# Exceptions of "remember somebody doing something"

Tags: tense

I studied the general use of "remember sb doing sth" such as

> I remember him **telling** me in the hospital when we finally saw him at
>   three thirty in ...

But there are also some exceptions,

> I remember we **talked** about your not wanting to discuss your past.
>
> I remember I **used** to look at it and try to see the resemblance.

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first sentence involves the use of remember with a [gerund](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/using-forget-regret-remember/).

The two 'exceptions' that you quote are actually a different usage, involving a **that-clause**. Many English speakers omit the **that**, but we know it should really be there:

> I remember [that] we talked about your not wanting to discuss your past.
>
> I remember [that] I used to look at it and try to see the resemblance.

The first 'exception' can be rewritten using a gerund:

> I remember us talking about your not wanting to discuss your past.

The second 'exception' can't be rewritten using using a gerund, because there is no gerund form of the expression **used to**. If you omitted the **used to**, you could use the gerunds of **look** and **try**:

> I remember looking at it and trying to see the resemblance.